# VBA returning incorrect month dates word

Tags: vba, ms-word, filenames

I have an issue with the following code for some reason when creating the files it only goes the 30th not the 31st on the correct months and in February it creates up to the 30th. The code is designed to create folder for each month then create a months worth of files from 1 master document. The original code I used worked but did not create the folders.

This is the code returning the error

```
 Sub Folder()

    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Dim fso As FileSystemObject     ' ''early binding. Requires reference to MS Scripting runtime
    'Set fso = New FileSystemObject     ''early binding

    Dim myYear As Long
    Dim endOfMonth As Long
    Dim filePathStub As String

    filePathStub = "c:\user\test briefing sheet\2019\" ' path to create folders at"

    myYear = 19

    Dim monthsArray() As Variant

    monthsArray = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "April", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

   Dim currentMonth As Long

   For currentMonth = LBound(monthsArray) To UBound(monthsArray)

       Dim folderName As String

       folderName = monthsArray(currentMonth) & " " & CStr(myYear)

       folderName = fso.CreateFolder(folderName)

       endOfMonth = CLng(Format$(dhLastDayInMonth(DateSerial(myYear, currentMonth + 1, 0)), "dd"))

       Dim currentDay As Long

       For currentDay = 1 To endOfMonth

           ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=folderName & Application.PathSeparator & monthsArray(currentMonth) & " " & currentDay, FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument

       Next currentDay

   Next currentMonth

End Sub

Function dhLastDayInMonth(Optional dtmDate As Date = 0) As Date
    ' Return the last day in the specified month.
    If dtmDate = 0 Then
        ' Did the caller pass in a date? If not, use
        ' the current date.
        dtmDate = Date
    End If
    dhLastDayInMonth = DateSerial(Year(dtmDate), _
     Month(dtmDate) + 1, 0)

End Function
```

This was the original code

```
    Sub Mine()
     Dim DateStr, FileStr As String
      DateStr = Format$(Date, "DD")
      FileStr = DateStr & ".docx"

      ActiveDocument.Save
      ChangeFileOpenDirectory "c:\user\test briefing sheet\2019\"
      ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=FileStr, FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument

End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=folderName & Application.PathSeparator & monthsArray(currentMonth) & " " & currentDay, FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument
```

currentDay is Long, while you are trying to use it as string. I'd code it as follows:

```
Dim documentName as string
documentName = monthsArray(currentMonth) & " " & CStr(currentDay)
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=folderName & Application.PathSeparator & documentName, FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument
```

Also, I'd re-write this line:

```
endOfMonth = CLng(Format$(dhLastDayInMonth(DateSerial(myYear, currentMonth + 1, 0)), "dd"))
```

as:

```
endOfMonth = DAY(dhLastDayInMonth(DateSerial(myYear, currentMonth + 1, 0)))
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this out and it is still creating the 31st of February and won't create the 31st of December. Not sure why?

Comment: Arrays in VBA start from 0, not from 1, so this might be the issue. To fix it, add Option Base 1 to the top of your module

Comment: Alternatively, you can add 1 to your function call: endOfMonth = DAY(dhLastDayInMonth(DateSerial(myYear, (currentMonth+1) + 1, 0)))

Comment: you'll have to excuse my lack of knowledge as I am relatively new to this but what to you mean by the the above?

Comment: When you wrote this: For currentMonth = LBound(monthsArray) To UBound(monthsArray)
You probably meant "For Month = 1 to Month = 12 ....."
But what is actually happening is "For Month = 0 to Month = 11 ... "

Comment: Because arrays in VBA start from 0, not from 1. I.e, monthArray(0) = "Jan", monthArray(1) = "Feb". So LBound(monthsArray) means 0. When you put 0 as a month number into DateSerial, it gives you wrong result (month 0 does not exist)

Comment: thank you this has now fixed it and is running as I need it to. thanks for your help.